# How to list all uploaded videos (URL) of a YouTube channel with API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

[This article](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos) shows how to get all uploaded videos from a particular channel in version 2, but I couldn't figure out how to do it with version 3.

Is it possible? Most of the version 3 articles just talk about searching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), you will find all Data API v3 references.

It takes few steps;

1) You [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) the specific channel that upload is done.

2) You resolve [uploads playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).

3) You can iterate inside this [playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) through [playlist items](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) for each video.

Here's an [Java example](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-myuploads-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_myuploads_sample/MyUploads.java). You can find other language examples inside [this project](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples) as well.