# How can I get all videos for a given channel?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to be able to retrieve Youtube videos from a Youtube channel.

My goal is to display them on a page. Currently I do it manually by getting an iframe like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/snRkGatdzm0" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am aware about Youtube API. I could not find a way to use it to get all videos from a channel.

So for example like the above I would just need the link Id --> `snRkGatdzm0`.

I prefer to work with php so If I get an array of video Id. I would just loop through them something like this:

```
foreach ($youtubevideos as $youtubevideo) {
    echo '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$youtubevideo"></iframe>'
}
```

note: the loop might be wrong (I added this fake loop because I know you guys love to see code lol)

Please advice.

---

I don't know if I am clear enough, I just want to be able to get all videos links from a channel so I can display them in a page. I don't want to hardcode it. That's all to make it short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to achieve what you want using YouTube API 2.0.

This is just quick and dirty way to do it. Keep in mind it will be deprecated soon because YouTube 3.0 is out already.

```
    $channelName ='YourChannelName';
    $channelURL ="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$channelName/uploads";
    $xml=simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($channelURL));


    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
        //Get each link
        $link = $entry->id;
        //Retrieve video id from link
        $link_array = explode('/',$link);
        $video_id = array_pop($link_array);
        //Create the iframe
        echo "<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$video_id\"></iframe>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get xml data about videos from youtube from the following URL where `channelname` is the name of the youtube channel.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/channelname/uploads
```

example below

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheEllenShow/uploads
```

You can use DOmDOcument or SimpleXMl to parse the xml and fetch the data.

example code

```
   $channelURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheEllenShow/uploads'; 
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($channelURL);
```

You can loop through `entry` node to get the video information. Also there is a `link` node which will hold additional information about the channel. You can also specify the start index and  limit of videos by appending the following parameter to URL `?start-index=1&max-results=25`.
example:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheEllenShow/uploads?start-index=26&max-results=25
```

Hope this helps you.

[Updated part for user]

```
$channelURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/snRkGatdzm0';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($channelURL);
$title = $xml->title; //Gets the title
$ChannelAuthor = $xml->author;  //Get the author tag to get the channel name
$channelName =$ChannelAuthor->uri; //Channel name fetched

$videoURL ="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$channelName/uploads";
$videoXml = simplexml_load_file($videoURL);
$title = $videoXml->title;//Get Title from video url
//Now loop through video information
foreach ($videoXml->entry as $entry) {
  $video = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
  // get video URL
  $URL = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watchURL = $URL['url'];//video URL
  $thmb = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
  $videoThumb = $thmb['url'];//gets the video thumb nail
  ..........
}
```

You can check the xml and retrieve its values as above

Comment: Thanks bro, you understood my question. I am more a JSON guy but I dont mind working with `XML`. Do you know how I can get the information from the node `snRkGatdzm0`

Comment: I am trying to tweak your code to get the link of each videos. What is `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` why do I need to use yahoo?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `DOM` and `explode()`

```
<?php
$html='<iframe width="560" height="315"
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/snRkGatdzm0"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $tag) {
    $ylink=$tag->getAttribute('src');
    }

$ylink = explode('/',$ylink);
echo $ylink = array_pop($ylink);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
snRkGatdzm0
```

### To get an array of links....

Do like this...

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $tag) {
    $ylink[]=$tag->getAttribute('src'); //<---- Just make this $ylink as an array as shown.
    }
```

After that subject like this.. to get just your ids...

```
$linkids = array_map('processIds',$ylink);

function processIds($v)
{
 $v = explode('/',$v);
 $v = array_pop($v);
 return $v;
}

print_r($linkids);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
snRkGatdzm0
rdd52d9z034
...
```

Comment: maybe I wasnt clear enough, I want to be able to get all videos links from a channel so I can display them in a page.

Comment: Please forgive me my lack of details. If for example I give you a channel like [this](http://www.youtube.com/user/MotherlandBoy) how can you code a page to display all videos from that channel. So you don't have to hardcode anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Since the gdata Api will be deprecated soon, your best bet is to use Data API to get the videos from that channel's playlist.

Here's a more detailed answer. [How to list all uploaded videos (URL) of a YouTube channel with API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632947/how-to-list-all-uploaded-videos-url-of-a-youtube-channel-with-api-v3/16636631#16636631)

You can use [Google Javascript client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) to achieve this on your website.