# YouTube API Playlists list does not give all videos in the playlist

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am a content owner of YouTube channels. When I generate a video report from YouTube web page, I am getting a result of 304k total videos. But when I query using YouTube Data API using the method discussed here [How to list all uploaded videos (URL) of a YouTube channel with API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632947/how-to-list-all-uploaded-videos-url-of-a-youtube-channel-with-api-v3/16636631#16636631), I am getting a lesser count (~270k). Some of these missing videos are removed videos from YouTube when I manually looked them up.

What might be the reason for other missing videos when I query the API? Is it because they might be private videos? If yes, how to get videoIds of such videos? What query to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like, yes, the reason was indeed due to Private/Unlisted videos under the content owner.